# Rails 3, IE assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, sprockets

Is there a good practice to organizing stylesheet/javascript asset files specifically for IE browsers with asset pipeline enabled in Rails 3? For example, I do not want to litter my **.html.erb** files with conditional comments similar to below for browser detections.

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I ripped all that out of my apps a year or more ago.  I rely on jquery, jquery-ui and simple_form.  This seems compatible with IE 7+ Firefox & Safari with no browser checking.  I assume it's all being handled out of sight in those systems and their attendant css stuff.  I honestly can't understand how ANYBODY tolerates having to deal with browser detection!  Cross Browser Compatibility was such a nightmare before I finally just stopped doing it, thank god my apps are more business like.  I'd hate to have to develop leading edge consumer stuff AND deal with cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into a partial in `app/views/layouts/`. This is also what Michael Hartl does with HTML5 Shim his tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-partials